# How should I name static functions in IDA?

Tags: ida

In C a static function is scoped to a source file so you can have multiple static functions with the same name as long as they are in different files.

Does IDA have a way to express this or do I have to add a prefix to names myself? I know I can mark functions as being static and associate a sourcefile with a range (using `add_sourcefile`) but this doesn't seem to resolve naming conflicts.

Comment: Are you working with an executable with debug information ?

Comment: @ws yes but the debug information is limited and in a weird format so I had to write a script to extract the info.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, what you're looking for is this IDA plugin...

```
for api_row in api_matrix:
    l = api_row[0]
    print l
    apis = api_row[1:]
    for api in apis:
        ref_addrs = CodeRefsTo(LocByName(api),0)
        for ref in ref_addrs:
            func_addr = LocByName(GetFunctionName(ref))
            func_name = GetFunctionName(ref)
            if l not in func_name:
                MakeNameEx(func_addr , l + '_' + func_name , SN_NOWARN)

print "complete"
```

Credits goes to: http://hooked-on-mnemonics.blogspot.fr/2012/06/automated-generic-function-naming-in.html

I recommend reading that article to learn how to use it. ^